# Are there negative implications to changing the from email header?

Tags: php, email, mailgun

We're sending email via Mailgun for a client. And the client would like us to change the `from` email header so that it matches the email address of the user submitting the form (their email address is a text input field).

Beyond validation concerns - what implications are there to doing this? And is there a "safe" or "best practice" way of doing this at all? I thought that this was generally frowned upon as a spammy practice, but I can't seem to find much information about this.

I've changed the `reply-to` header to the email address the user submits, however it would be desirable if we could change the presentation of the email such that it looks like it's come from the user submitting the form (I don't want to get into technical/usability reasons about why this is desirable, but suffice to say that it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when the receiving mail server does a reverse lookup on the domain and your server doesn't show as being one that it is expected to come from (e.g. gmail.com would expect to be coming from something like smtp.gmail.com) your server's IP could end up being added to the Blacklisting/Spam Registries.

Generally speaking, we tend not to send from unless we have the SFP listing in the domain A records.